# Persistence in docker

Tags: sql, docker

i created a compose container with two: one for the app and one for sql...i also created a volume to persist the data and now i have a problem: is it normal that the db is written only to the volume and not on Mysql?
This is my compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  server:
    image: myshop:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/my_shop?useSSL=false
    volumes:
     - myshopstorage:/var/lib/docker/volumes/myshop_myshopstorage/_data

    networks:
      - myshop-net
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - myshopstorage:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - myshop-net
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_shop?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSLL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_shop

networks:
  myshop-net:
    external: false

volumes:
  myshopstorage:
    external: false
```

How can i write the data in the volume on the mysql database?
Right now data are persistent only in docker volume

A screen of my volume:

[volume scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27DAM.png)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your volume setup.  The setup in the `mysqldb` container looks correct, but you shouldn't need to mount the opaque database storage into your application container, nor should you need to set a Spring environment variable in your non-Java database container.  When you say the data is being written to the volume but not the database, what behavior exactly are you seeing?

Comment: I mean that the database with the tables is created in the volume, and if I try to make crud calls they work, but if I open mysql workbench the db doesn't even exist.
I'm just getting started with docker, could I have confused some concepts?

Comment: That sounds like the workbench tool is connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: Can be a volume settings problem? Or some in the datasource?